# FME Server for Linux and Excel reader/writer

Tags: fme-form

I have an FME model with Excel reader and writer.
In FME Desktop help it is stated: "the format is available only on Windows."

So, as I understand it will not be possible to run this model on FME Server for linux?
Or there is any possibility to do it?

PS we have no FME Server yet. Right now we try to choose the right version FME Server for linux or for windows. Linux is prefered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to use FME to read Excel on Linux and this is not likely to be supported by us any time soon. The libraries we use to read Excel are only available on Windows.  There are other formats not available for FME on Linux as well usually due to the availability of 3rd party libraries (see this [page](http://www.safe.com/fme/format-search/) ).  If you have a choice I would suggest Windows due to a larger list of supported formats and the fact that we have many more users running FME Server on Windows.

Comment: Could you please explain if you are supporting open document formats which could be opened using Excel?